# sns.heatmap y axis not being overwritten

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, yaxis

**Goal**: I want to create a heatmap from a dataframe which has 2 indexes. The 2nd index, called 'Profile_Name', is also used to loop through the dataframe to create several heatmaps.

**Problem**: The sns.heatmap does not allow me to change the values on the y axis.

**code to recreate the dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Monday', 1, 'Sebastian', 3], 
                   ['Monday', 2, 'Sebastian', 6],
                   ['Monday', 3, 'Living room', 10], 
                   ['Tuesday', 1,'Sebastian', 6],
                   ['Tuesday', 2,'Sebastian', 3], 
                   ['Tuesday', 3,'Sebastian', 8], 
                   ['Wednesday', 1,'Sebastian', 6],
                   ['Wednesday', 2,'Sebastian', 3], 
                   ['Wednesday', 3,'Sebastian', 9], 
                   ['Tuesday', 1,'Living room', 6], 
                   ['Monday', 2,'Living room', 10]], 
                  columns=['Weekday', 'Hour', 'Profile_Name', 'Counts'])

heatmap_df = df.pivot_table(index=('Hour', 'Profile_Name') ,columns='Weekday',values='Counts', aggfunc=lambda x:x).fillna(0)
heatmap_df.head()
```

**The code to create the heatmaps**

```
Names =  df.Profile_Name.unique()

for Profile in Names:

    plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
    sns.heatmap(heatmap_df[heatmap_df.index.get_level_values('Profile_Name').isin([Profile])], annot= True, fmt='g', cmap="Blues")
    plt.title(Profile, fontsize = 20) # title with fontsize 20
    plt.xlabel('Weekday', fontsize = 15) # x-axis label with fontsize 15
    plt.ylabel('Time', fontsize = 15) # y-axis label with fontsize 15
    #ax.set_yticks(range(0,24)) ## doesnt work

    
    plt.show()
```

**How the heatmap looks**
[image]

How do I remove the second index 'Profile_Name', shown as 'Sebastian' in the screenshot, from the y axis?
I want the y axis to only show the 'Hour' index or to completely overwrite it and set the values 0-23 on the y axis.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @TrentonMcKinney :) 
Hope I did it correctly with the new edit of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest fix is to drop the unneeded index from the dataframe (at the time of plotting). Alternatively, you could call `ax.set_yticklabels(range(0,24), rotation=0)` if previously `ax` has been given the correct value (either via `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)` or via `ax = plt.gca()`. Such will only work if all 24 levels are present in the dataframe.

Note that your code seems to mix the "new" [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) with the old `pyplot` interface.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 2000
weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Hour': np.random.randint(0, 24, N),
                   'Profile_Name': np.random.choice(['Johan', 'Sebastian', 'Stephanie'], N),
                   'Weekday': np.random.choice(weekdays, N),
                   'Value': np.random.randint(1, 4, N)
                   })
df['Weekday'] = pd.Categorical(df['Weekday'], weekdays)  # set a fixed order
heatmap_df = df.pivot_table(values='Value', index=['Hour', 'Profile_Name'], columns=['Weekday'])

Names = heatmap_df.index.get_level_values('Profile_Name').unique()

for Profile in Names:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
    sns.heatmap(heatmap_df[heatmap_df.index.get_level_values('Profile_Name').isin([Profile])].droplevel(1, axis=0),
                annot=True, fmt='g', cmap="Blues", ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(Profile, fontsize=20)
    ax.set_xlabel('Weekday', fontsize=15)  
    ax.set_ylabel('Time', fontsize=15) 
    # ax.set_yticklabels(range(0,24), rotation=0)
    plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap with second index removed]

Comment: Thanks @johanC, it worked 

and thank you for the read on the Pyplot interface